# maven-surefire-plugin: How to hide test result in HTML report

Tags: junit, maven-surefire-plugin

Is there anyway to hide the test result of some test cases in the HTML report generated by the maven-surefire-plugin? It's not about skipping some test cases, just hiding the results in the generated report.

I'm aware of the @Ignore support in JUnit4 but it does not work when we inherit from the TestCase class.

Comment: not aware of a feature to hide report just for a single test. But you can hide report for successful tests using `-DshowSuccess=false` with maven-surefire-report-plugin